# MySQL Wildcard on JSON array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I'm trying to extract an ID (5384) that is inside an array contained in JSON using wildcards. The problem I'm having is that the position of the ID doesn't have a fixed position for each element in that array. An example of my JSON in that array is like this (where "id":5384 could occupy different indexed positions):

```
{  
  "id":7465115,
  "name":"BCA_WS_FBX_Nielsen PRIZM_Test_Unlock_1x1",
  "advertiser_id":155085,
  "pixels":[  
  {  
   "id":416491,
   "pixel_template_id":null,
  },
  {  
   "id":5384,
   "pixel_template_id":null,
  }
  ]
}
```

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT id, json FROM PROD_APPNEXUS.dimension_json_creatives 
WHERE JSON LIKE ('%pixels%_%"id":5384,%') AND MEMBER_ID = 364
```

I'm trying to extract only items that are in the pixels array and have an ID of 5384.

Any comments as to how to achieve this would be highly valued, thanks!

UPDATE: MySQL version 5.6.17

Sam

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the underscore in the LIKE expression?

Comment: I was thinking perhaps using %_% would be able to search for "pixels" then ignore all characters that aren't "id":5384, until you get to "id":5384.

Comment: Sure, but you'd miss the element if it's the first occurrence in the array. In any case, consider taking a look at MySQL's 5.7 JSON search function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: I thought the %_% would just ignore the [{ brackets and not the first occurrence of that ID (if this was the case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I would think of is to use the REGEXP syntax of MySQL:

```
SELECT id, json FROM PROD_APPNEXUS.dimension_json_creatives 
WHERE (JSON REGEXP '("pixels":\[)?.*"id":5384') AND MEMBER_ID = 364
```

Comment: Working for my version. Thank-you

Answer (score 5):

Try:

[12.6 The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). MySQL 5.7.8+

```sql
SELECT
  `id`,
  `json` -- Data Type JSON
FROM
  `PROD_APPNEXUS`.`dimension_json_creatives`
WHERE
  JSON_CONTAINS(`json`, '{"id": 5384}', '$.pixels') AND
  `MEMBER_ID` = 364;
```

**UPDATE**

Using 5.6.17, one option is:

```sql
SELECT
  `id`,
  `json`
FROM
  `PROD_APPNEXUS`.`dimension_json_creatives`
WHERE
  `json` REGEXP '"pixels":\\[.*"id":5384.*]' AND
  MEMBER_ID = 364;
```

Performance may be affected depending on the number of tuples in the table.

Comment: How could i update the value ? ( 5384 in this case )

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT
  `id`,
   JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.pixels') as pixels
FROM
  `PROD_APPNEXUS`.`dimension_json_creatives`
WHERE
  JSON_CONTAINS(`json`, '{"id": 5384}', '$.pixels') AND
  `MEMBER_ID` = 364;
```

Please note that you need a version >= 5.7.8 for MySQL for this to work